# Why do eigenvalues of Hermitian/Unitary maps have to be distinct for the eigenvectors to be orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Some things I know:

1. Eigenvectors corresponding to DISTINCT eigenvalues are orthogonal for Hermitian and Unitary maps.
2. Hermitian and Unitary maps are normal.
3. Normal maps have an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

Surely from this it follows that all eigenvectors of Hermitian and Unitary maps will always be mutually orthogonal, irrespective of whether or not the eigenvalues are the distinct, as we know that the eigenvectors form an orthogonal basis, so by definition of a basis, we can't have any more or fewer eigenvectors that aren't mutually orthogonal with the others.

Edit:
I know this isn't true but just wondering where the error in this line of reasoning is. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't really understand your argument in the non-distinct case, but no, a general basis of eigenvalues need not be orthogonal if one of the eigenspaces has dimension at least $2$. This is because there are many non-orthogonal bases of subspaces of dimension at least $2$. For example,$$U = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1}$$could have the following non-orthogonal basis of eigenvectors:$$\left(\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\pmatrix{1\\1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: So my error was in my interpretation of the third thing, it would be more accurate to say that we can always choose eigenvectors of normal maps such that they will form a basis, because given a degenerate eigenvalue (in this case 1), its eigenspace will span at least 2 dimensions and because any linear combination of two eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue will be itself an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue by linearity of U, it follows that we can always obtain n mutually orthogonal eigenvectors from an n-dimensional eigenspace?

Comment: That’s right. An orthogonal eigenbasis can alway be chosen, but not every eigenbasis is orthogonal.

Comment: Every vector is an eigenvector of the identity matrix. Not all distinct pairs of vectors are orthogonal.